# Progressive Matrix question - lines, squares and circles

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

I found a [free logical reasoning test](https://www.123test.com/logical-reasoning-test/) which consisted of 10 questions. I managed to solve all the other questions correctly except for the last one:

[image]

I could not find a pattern for the squares and circles. I could only find one in the lines, which is that the lines move up as the sequence continues. However, this leaves me with 3 possible answers. I could only guess the answer and hope that I get it correct. Which one is the correct answer, and what is the correct reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the answer is

> Option D (bottom-right corner)

If you look at

> the columns you see that the bar remains in the same position, the circle moves downwards and shift color and the square moves upwards and shift color

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer, the answer is:

> The option on the bottom right corner

Because:

> You don't actually need to look at the second picture. The rule is, the shapes on the sides switch positions, and the line moves to the top. It looks something like this: [image]
>  
>  Therefore, the only possible answer would be 4(the option on the bottom right).